# Error in Terraform while upgrading Spark version of Azure Synapse

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I'm receiving the following error when trying to upgrade the spark version of our Azure Synapse environment from 3.2 to 3.3. This error is obtained through `terraform apply`:

```
    Starting: Terraform Apply
    ==============================================================================
    Task         : Bash
    Description  : Run a Bash script on macOS, Linux, or Windows
    Version      : 3.214.0
    Author       : Microsoft Corporation
    Help         : https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/bash
    ==============================================================================
    Generating script.
    ========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
    /usr/bin/bash /home/vsts/work/_temp/xxxxxx.sh
    ╷
    │ Error: expected spark_version to be one of [2.4 3.1 3.2], got 3.3
    │ 

│   with azurerm_synapse_spark_pool.dlake_spark_pool,
│   on synapse.tf line 153, in resource "azurerm_synapse_spark_pool" "dlake_spark_pool":
│  153:   spark_version        = 3.3
│ 
╵
##[error]Bash exited with code '1'.
Finishing: Terraform Apply
```

Which is very strange, because the [documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/synapse_spark_pool) about the synapse spark pool says that it should be possible to upgrade. Specifically, the following line:

> spark_version - (Optional) The Apache Spark version. Possible values are 2.4 , 3.1 , 3.2 and 3.3. Defaults to 2.4.

What is happening, and why can't I upgrade my spark version even though docs say it's possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With *any* additional library you have between you and the actual API you risk them getting out of sync with each other. Very possible that that is / was the case here.

Luckily terraform did have an update to the provider and supports that version but most likely you use an old version of the azurem provider. Check e.g. [the docs for 3.23.0](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/3.23.0/docs/resources/synapse_spark_pool) where the possible values do not include 3.3 but stop at 3.2
Therefore you need to check the provider version you use and upgrade it to a version that does support the features you are interested in, or just upgrade to the current latest / 3.55.0

Comment: I see - am using azurerm_provider 3.22 indeed. Will upgrade - if that solves the problem I will accept your answer!

Comment: @Psychotechnopath ah, so close with my lucky guess of 3.23 :D

Comment: Haha, close indeed! Upgrading azurerm_provider solved the issue. Many thanks!